# How can I accelerate simple matlab code by GPU device

Tags: performance, matlab, cuda

I have encountered some problems while I was simulating simple code on Matlab GPU computing.

first case, I compared fft2 computation time of CPU with GPU

**By CPU:**

```
A=rand(2000);
tic
for K=1:200
   yy=fft2(A);
end
toc
```

**By GPU:**

```
A=gpuArray(A);
tic
for K=1:200
   yy=fft2(A);
end
toc
```

It took 5.984209 sec by CPU and 0.036392 sec by GPU. It seem to be a reasonable result.

At second case, I tried simple calculation.

**By CPU:**

```
D=rand(1,2000);
E=rand(1,2000);
tic
for K=1:2000
  pp=sqrt(D(K)^2+E(K)^2)/E(K);
end
toc
```

**By GPU:**

```
F=gpuArray(D);
G=gpuArray(E);
tic
for K=1:2000
  qq=sqrt(F(K)^2+G(K)^2)/G(K);
end
toc
```

It took 0.002940 sec by CPU and 2.699595 sec by GPU. It's a very strange result!

**Why is this happening?** I know that it can be faster by using 'arrayfun' for gpuArray inputs.

**Is there no way to calculate 'for loop' by using GPU except for arrayfun?**

I know that one GPU has a few thousands cores.  **In that case, is it possible to use 'parfor loop' by using one GPU?**

For non built in function, it is difficult to fit all conditions suitable for 'arrayfun'.

So, I think it is natural to using 'for loop' in a self-function. However, from the results above, 'for loop' makes the total process slow for gpuArray inputs.(It is slower than a CPU result)

So, **I think all of general codes cannot be converted into 'GPU form' by using full advantage of GPU computing. Is that right?**

Comment: Well, the GPU is faster when performing multiple calculations in parallel. In your first example, you calculated the fft of a 2000x2000 matrix for 200 times. In your second example you calculate 2000 times a single value. This suffers from overhead by gpu handling. Have you compared the 2nd example vectorized: `qq = sqrt(F.^2+G.^2)./G;`

Answer (score 1):

As you have discovered, a FOR loop over scalar elements of `gpuArray` data performs terribly badly, and is almost always a bad idea. In general, you need to use either vectorised operations or `arrayfun` to get good performance. If that doesn't give you enough flexibility or performance, you can always use the [`CUDAKernel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parallel.gpu.cudakernel.html) interface or the [GPU MEX interface](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/run-mex-functions-containing-cuda-code.html).